# Cannot set property 'size' of undefined even though module was exported

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJS development, and I've set up Visual Studio Code to develop JavaScript for node applications.

I was following a lecture on Pluralsight, and we had just made it to the section about Objects. What the teacher did was make two scripts, `dice.js` and `program.js` and put them in the same folder. I did the same.

They look like this:

dice.js:

```
var die = {
    size: 6,
    totalRolls: 0,
    roll: function() {
        this.totalRolls++;
        return Math.ceil(this.size * Math.random());
    }
};

exports.game = die;
```

program.js

```
var dice = require("./dice");
var die = dice.die;

die.size = 10;

console.log(die.roll());
console.log(die.roll());
console.log(die.roll());
console.log("Total rolls " + die.totalRolls);

console.log(die);
```

Whenever I try and run the program.js file through Visual Studio Code however, it tells me that the property "size" is undefined. If I try and use the dot connector I get this:

[image]

So the size isn't there. The instructors program worked just fine, but me doing this keeps giving me the error. I've looked everywhere to try and understand what could have gone wrong. My guess is that I don't use `require()` correctly, or something. Coming from Strongly Typed compiled languages, this is very confusing to me.

What did I miss?

Comment: You are exporting it as game and trying to access it as die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exporting a thing called game but importing die, so naturally this wont work.

```
// dice.js
exports.game = die;
// program.js
var dice = require("./dice");
var die = dice.die; // <- this is wrong, change to .game:
var die = dice.game;
```

Comment: Okay. I'll go back and change my code. But why does it work for the instructor then?? Look at [this picture](http://puu.sh/wRFNR/984e267239.jpg) and then at [this picture](http://puu.sh/wRFPV/3934fa2680.jpg)

Comment: @Vipar the very first screenshot - the instructor exports as `die` (`exports.die = die` you have `exports.game = die`)